# PHP: Replace first part of an url

Tags: php

I would like to change the first part of my url.

I have this url

```
www.website.com/download/long-file-name-123
```

I would like to change the "download" part to "downloads" like this.

```
www.website.com/downloads/long-file-name-123
```

The problem is that the url can also look like this:

```
www.website.com/download/files/file/long-file-name-123
```

So i need some way to always only change the first part of the url,

Comment: what did you do for that so far?

Comment: I think you might find parse_url() helpful http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Is this URL your website address on which you're receiving requests or is it another site (e.g. for cURL requests)?

Comment: *"I have this url"* -- that is not an URL; an [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) starts with a scheme (f.e. `http`) followed by a colon (`:`) and so on. F.e. `http://www.website.com/download/long-file-name-123`.

Answer (score 1):

```
php > $url = 'www.website.com/download/long-file-name-123';
php > $newUrl = str_replace('www.website.com/download', 'www.website.com/downloads', $url);
php > var_dump($newUrl);
string(44) "www.website.com/downloads/long-file-name-123"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo str_replace("download","downloads","www.website.com/download/long-file-name-123");
?>
```

For First occurrence of download

```
<?php
$urls = array("www.website.com/download/long-file-name-123","www.website.com/download/files/file/long-file-name-123");
$arrlength = count($urls);
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++)
{
    $pos = strpos($urls[$x], "download");
    if ($pos !== false) {
        $newstring = substr_replace($urls[$x], "downloads", $pos, strlen("download"));
        echo ($newstring);
        echo ("\n");
    }
}
?>
```

Output:

```
www.website.com/downloads/long-file-name-123
www.website.com/downloads/files/file/long-file-name-123
```

Live Demo:

> http://tpcg.io/7tv7nF